# SQL Select больше или равно

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться
Есть таблица со колонкой price (тип int) в ней записи 50, 75, 100...
Пытаюсь вывести значения от 51 до 100

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE price >= 51 AND price <= 100`

```
price BETWEEN 51 AND 100
```

- тоже не работает

Получаю только 100, в чем проблема?

Comment: пропустили название колонки

Comment: Исправил колонка price

Comment: после AND тоже надо *price* <= 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE price >= 51 AND price <= 100

Comment: Это запрос который ваи нужен. Выше в комментариях вам об этом же пишут.

Comment: Извините, опечатка у меня такой запрос не работает!

Comment: Так значит в таблицу нет других значений.

Comment: Если бы "таблицу неправильно указал, либо название колонки" не получал бы ничего, а так "Получаю только 100"!

Comment: Сделайте SELECT * FROM table Order by price

Comment: Получая все значения отсортированные по price

Comment: Ну и там есть значения между 51 и 100?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46112/discussion-between---and-andreyvitovtov).